# Xamarin Form's Resource dictionary type not found in namespace xmlns when debugging using iPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My solution consist of 3 project:

1. My backend project with assembly My_Test_App (portable)
2. My_Test_App.Android
3. My_Test_App.iOS

In the backend project, I have this XAML page code (Please forgive the name)

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="My_Test_App.Pages.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:My_Test_App.Converters;assembly=My_Test_App"
    xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:My_Test_App.Effects;assembly=My_Test_App"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:My_Test_App.ViewModels;assembly=My_Test_App"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:My_Test_App.Views;assembly=My_Test_App">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:Converter1 x:Key="conv1" />
            <converters:Converter2 x:Key="conv2" />
            <converters:Converter3 x:Key="conv3" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>
```

It works on android and iPhone simulator, but when i tested it on the real iPhone, i get this error:
`Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 13:14. Type converters:Converter1 not found in xmlns clr-namespace:My_Test_App.Converters;assembly=My_Test_App`

My code for Converter1 in the backend project:

```
namespace My_Test_App.Converters
{
    public class Converter1: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool original = (bool)value;
            return !original;
        }       
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public My_Test_App()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help with this please? I have a few suspect here:

1. Underscore on assembly name, but i need to keep the current assembly name..
2. In the IOS project properties, i changed the linker Options in iOS Build section from "Link SDK only" to "Link all assemblies". But, if i don't change it, i got error "Could not AOT the assembly......."
3. Possible bug in the current xamarin version (mine is 4.2.2.11)

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Type converters:Converter1 not found**

The Xamarin linker uses static analysis to determine what `IL` code can be removed from your assemblies to reduce the size and due to reflection invoke usage from `Xamarin.Form`, the `IValueConverter`-based class appears not to be used.

In your Xamarin.Forms (PCL) project, add a `PreserveAttribute` class:

```
public sealed class PreserveAttribute : System.Attribute {
    public bool AllMembers;
    public bool Conditional;
}
```

Now add the [Preserve] w/ AllMembers attribute to your `IValueConverter` class to inform the Linker to skip this class:

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public class Converter1: IValueConverter
{
  ~~~
}
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/

Comment: Thanks, the preserve attribute works. However i'm not sure what it means that IValueConverter is not used since i need to implement that interface (which means it's being used right?)

Comment: @prinnny Thanks, that was worded incorrectly/poorly. I updated it to read `the IValueConverter-based class appears not to be used.` In your case, `Converter1` does not have a *direct* code reference since it is invoked via reflection and not a direct method call (that would be seen by the Linker). One item to note, using the `XAMLC` to pre-compile most of your XAML helps avoid *some* of these Linker issues as direct code references will be made: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/