# MissingMethodException in iOS app while using Xamarin's FileHelper Implementation

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I recently followed Xamarin's [SQLite tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) to install SQLite-net PCL. Everything works perfectly on the simulator in `Debug` mode but I'm getting crashes on startup in `Release` mode.

The exception is as follows:

**exception:**

> System.MissingMethodException

**message:**

> Default constructor not found for type MyApp.iOS.FileHelper

**stack trace:**

> at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
>   (int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main
>   (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr
>   delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
>   principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>   at MyApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in
>   /Users/{FilePath}/iOS/Main.cs:13

**What I've found**

So this `MyApp.iOS.FileHelper` is [Xamarin's code](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) that fetches the documents directory. The implementation goes like this:

In the **Forms** application we just have a contract:

```
public interface IFileHelper
{
    string GetLocalFilePath(string filename);
}
```

In the `MyApp.iOS` project we define a dependency:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {  
        public FileHelper() { }

        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
             string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "Databases");

            if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
            }

            return Path.Combine(libFolder, filename); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I am using it:

```
DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("MyAppDatabase.db3")
```

The application works as expected in Debug mode. So either the Dependency Service is behaving differently in Release or the Documents Directory is different in Release.

### My Question

How can avoid this exception in release mode?

**Dependency Info:**

Xamarin Forms 2.3.3.193
Sqlite-net-pcl 1.2.1

---

**update:**

What I've tried:

- Added a default constructor, yields no change
- Tried different linker possibilities, yields no change

Comment: Have you tried to add to add an empty constructor to FileHelper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Form's Resource dictionary type not found in namespace xmlns when debugging using iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931962/xamarin-forms-resource-dictionary-type-not-found-in-namespace-xmlns-when-debugg)

Comment: @Daniel yes I have

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: @SushiHangover So I should decorate my FileHelper class in my iOS project with `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]`? I'll try it

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Yes, that should be it

Comment: @SushiHangover this moves me on to a new exception (finally). I believe you're correct, I may vote to close this as a duplicate as well. Thanks!

Comment: @DanBeaulieu No problem, post another question if you need help on the "next" problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please note**: I tried voting to close this question as a duplicate. It clearly
>   failed to be closed as such.

Based on comments point to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932246/1664443) from [SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover), this is what resolved my issue:

I needed to add decorate my FileHelper class in my iOS project with:

`[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]`

again, please go check out his original post here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932246/1664443

Answer (score 0):

From [Introduction to DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/)

> Note that every implementation must have a default (parameterless)
>   constructor in order for DependencyService to be able to instantiate
>   it. Parameterless constructors cannot be defined by the interface.

You need to add an empty constructor to your FileHelper class.

```
public FileHelper() {
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. I'll update my question to reflect.